# How do I ensure that a 'no results' view block is still refreshed by Block Refresh

Tags: 7, views, blocks, ajax

I have [Block Refresh](https://drupal.org/project/block_refresh) enabled on my site.  It does a great job refreshing content blocks unless the original block load contains zero results.  If a block is loaded without results, and a new node (which should appear in the block) is created, the new node will not appear in the block unless the page is refreshed.  It seems that the refresh code is not active unless the view is loaded with at least one item of content.  Is there a way to ensure that the view always loads?  I'm thinking that I need to change the 'no results' behavior in my view.

Edit =========

I am currently setting the 'no results' behavior to 'Global: Result summary' and setting the response to 'Empty'.  This seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the 'No Results' behavior to 'Global: result summery' and add some text to give as a response.  This will ensure that the view is rendered and active, even if there are no results.

This will allow block refresh to add new content as it become available.